# How to access an attribute with a computed name

Tags: xml, xslt

I want to read a value of attribute using a variable to compute its name:

```
<xsl:variable name="TopMan">
    <xsl:for-each select="//ALL_RESOURCES/*/*/*">
        <xsl:if test="contains(@Name,'Chan' )">
            <xsl:variable name="element_name" select="name(..)"/>
            <xsl:variable name="FChanSub" select="(//ALL_RESOURCES/*/*[$element_name = name()]/@UsedEle)"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="(//ALL_RESOURCES/*[(substring-before($element_name, '_')) = name()]/@[(concat('NEIBR_', $FChanSub)) = name()])"/>     
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:variable>
```

There is problem with line 6. Is the reading the value is Correct. Basically, I am having a structure NEIBR_HM1, NEIBR_NR, etc.. I want to read the value in NEIBR_(HM1 or NR).

Comment: I think you need [exslt-dynamic](http://exslt.org/dyn/index.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without seeing your input or expected output I can't be 100% sure, but I think you're pretty close: just change

```
@[(concat('NEIBR_', $FChanSub)) = name()]
```

to

```
@*[(concat('NEIBR_', $FChanSub)) = name()]
```